# My own library class shows up as decompiled

Tags: android, gradle

I have an interesting problem.
So, I have a module "MyOwnSDK" - my library.

1. If I go, make a new Demo app, and import my library manually (add module etc.), this library can be debugged easily.
2. If I go, make a new Demo app, but this time download the library using Gradle ("implementation "mylibrary:1.0"), the library part is not debuggable. Whenever I click on a function that is inside of a library, it opens a class that is readable and shows decompiled file (I see function name, but no implementation != no debugging).

Problem: How to make sure that using 2) approach I can also debug my code (so I can bugfix)?

Comment: did you publish a sources jar along with your library?

Comment: `My own library class shows up as decompiled` i think you actually meant that it shows up as compiled :)

Comment: @Henry If code was written by another person, how would one check that and how would one move forward solving my issue? Thanks.